# Is it possible to activate a conda environment prefixed with a path from VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

For example `conda create -p $PWD/env` will create a new conda environment prefixed with the current working directory.

To activate the environment, I use the command `conda activate $PWD/env`.

VSCode has no problems seeing the environment.  After selecting the correct interpreter and starting a new integrated terminal, VSCode tries to activate the environment with the following command `conda activate env` which does not work.

Is there a way to get VSCode to use the full path to activate the correct environment in the integrated terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the automatic activation if you would rather do it manually, but currently the support isn't structured for this situation. Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python to support your use case.